# Room database one-to-many Relation DAO error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I'm making a note app where each Note has a Label, and each Label has many Notes assigned to it. So it's a one-to-many relation in the database.
I created the entity classes following [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542) tutorial. but when I build the project it gives me an error in the DAO interface.  The error is

> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

But in build output it says the `getAllNotes()` function has a problem:

> NoteDao.java:17: error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [labelId,labelName] in com.hh.knotemessenger.data.LabelWithNotes even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [noteId,noteText,dateCreated,isArchived,noteLabelId]

**Note** class:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "note_table",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Label::class,
        parentColumns = ["labelId"],
        childColumns = ["noteLabelId"]
    )]
)
@Parcelize
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val noteId: Int = 0,
    val noteText: String,
    val dateCreated: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),
    val isArchived: Boolean = false,
    val noteLabelId: Int
) : Parcelable {
    val createdDateFormatted: String
        get() = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(dateCreated)
}
```

**Label** class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "label_table")
@Parcelize
data class Label(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val labelId: Int = 0,
    val labelName: String,
    val dateCreated: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
) : Parcelable
```

**LabelWithNotes** class:

```
data class LabelWithNotes(
    @Embedded val label: Label,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "labelId", entityColumn = "noteLabelId")
    val note: List<Note>
)
```

**NoteDao** interface:

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    fun getNotes(searchQuery: String, labelId: Int): Flow<List<LabelWithNotes>> =
        when (labelId) {
            1 -> getAllNotes(searchQuery)
            else -> getNotesByLabel(searchQuery, labelId)
        }

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table WHERE isArchived = 0 AND noteText LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' ")
    fun getAllNotes(searchQuery: String): Flow<List<LabelWithNotes>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table WHERE isArchived = 0 AND noteText LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' AND noteLabelId =:labelId")
    fun getNotesByLabel(searchQuery: String, labelId: Int): Flow<List<LabelWithNotes>>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Issue**
The issue you have is that you are trying to retrieve Labels from the note_table.

```
The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [labelId,labelName] in com.hh.knotemessenger.data.LabelWithNotes even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. 

Columns returned by the query: [noteId,noteText,dateCreated,isArchived,noteLabelId]
```

This is saying that the expected columns **labelId** and **labelName** are required but are not available and that the noteId .... columns are available

In short to find the Notes for each label you traverse the **label_table** not the **note_table**.

**Resolution** (sort of)
If you use:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM label_table")
fun getAllNotes(searchQuery: String): Flow<List<LabelWithNotes>>

@Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM label_table")
    fun getNotesByLabel(searchQuery: String, labelId: Int): Flow<List<LabelWithNotes>>
```

Then I believe that you will not get the error.

**However**, adding the WHERE clause referencing columns in the note_table will result in a failure to compile as the note_tabe is not included.

You could include a **JOIN** to allow the note_table columns to be included like:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM label_table JOIN note_table ON labelId = noteLabelId  WHERE isArchived = 0 AND noteText LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' ")
fun getAllNotes(searchQuery: String): Flow<List<LabelWithNotes>>

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM label_table JOIN note_table ON labelId = noteLabelId WHERE isArchived = 0 AND noteText LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' AND noteLabelId =:labelId")
fun getNotesByLabel(searchQuery: String, labelId: Int): Flow<List<LabelWithNotes>>
```

**BUT** that would not have the desired result. as the way that room treats **@Relation** is that it retrieves **ALL** notes for each label extracted irrespective of a WHERE clause that apparently limits the notes.

as per

> A convenience annotation which can be used in a POJO to automatically fetch relation entities. When the POJO is returned from a query, **all of its relations are also fetched by Room**.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation

You would also get warnings like:-

```
E:\AndroidStudioApps\SO67804070KotlinRoom\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\a\a\so67804070kotlinroom\NoteDao.java:27: warning: The query returns some columns [noteId, noteText, isArchived, noteLabelId] which are not used by a.a.so67804070kotlinroom.LabelWithNotes. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. You can annotate the method with @RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns to direct Room to rewrite your query to avoid fetching unused columns.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: labelId, labelName, dateCreated, noteId, noteText, dateCreated, isArchived, noteLabelId. Fields in a.a.so67804070kotlinroom.LabelWithNotes: labelId, labelName, dateCreated.
```

You may also end up retrieving duplicate labels with notes (the same notes).

I believe that what you may want is to have NotesWithLabel rather than LabelsWithNotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. But if I create a `NotesWithLabel` class, not only it's the opposite of what the documentation says, I'll have a problem when running queries that contain columns from label_table. I mean the problem won't be solved, just changes to something similar. Am I wrong?

Comment: You will always have issue of ALL children being retrieved whichever way when using @Relation as that's the way it works. However, considering your WHERE clause then at least you would only end up getting the appropriate notes with the label albeit that some labels may be duplicated.  However, really the question was about why you were getting the error and how to resolve that. How to get the data you want should really be another question.